# Can multiple WebGLRenderers render the same scene?

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to use two instances of `WebGLRenderer`, using two `Canvas`s to render the same scene?

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas1
});
renderer.setSize(100,100);
var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas2
});
renderer2.setSize(100,100);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100)
);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.z = 500;
scene.add(mesh);

function draw(){ 
    //try commenting the first render out
    //it will allow the other renderer to draw
    renderer.render(scene,camera); 
    renderer2.render(scene,camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

In this fiddle, when I do as above, I can only render on one canvas at a given time.
http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/sbdogbLw/1/

Comment: Seems like it's not possible - you must have two scenes (and two meshes): http://jsfiddle.net/sbdogbLw/2/

Comment: @Shomz any idea what the reason might be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple renderers rendering the same scene, provided they each have their own canvas (cf. [Multiple WebGLRenderer on a single canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314548/multiple-webglrenderer-on-a-single-canvas)). An example showing this is [Multisampled Renderbuffers](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multisam#webgl2_multisampled_renderbuffers). In the example the same scene is rendered with and without antialiasing.

The code used to create the renderers looks like this:

```
renderer1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer1.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer1.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer1.domElement );

renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer2.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );
```

The rendering itself is similarly straightforward:

```
renderer1.render( scene, camera );
renderer2.render( scene, camera );
```

Answer (score -1):

No but you can do a solution using viewports like [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html) or viewport and scissor settings like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608723/is-it-possible-to-enable-unbounded-number-of-renderers-in-three-js/30633132#30633132).

Note I didn't post the code to the first one because it's an uncommon solution. I didn't post the code to the second one because it's already on stack overflow.